# Animation synchronisation in Three.js with Tween.js

Tags: animation, three.js

I'm trying to animate sprites along a path in Three.js using Tween.js by chaining the animations in order to have something like this :

----@----@----@----@----@---- etc

Every sprite has its own tween animation, and I just delay each tween animation at the beginning. Each sprite has in fact N animations along the path (that is not a straight line) and I chain them to have a loop effect.

Everything goes well if the FPS is perfectly stable, but my problem is that if at some point I have a FPS drop, the animations of the different sprites are not in sync anymore, and the space between sprites is not equal anymore. I potentially end up with something like this :

---@--@----@-@-@-----@--- etc

I was wondering if there is a better approach for this, like having only one tween animation for all the sprites, but I don't know how to introduce the offset between each sprite on many line segments.

I cannot post the exact code has it is part of a bigger app, and won't be usable as is, but it looks like this :

```
// create animations
for each (sprite) {
    for each (segment) {
        var currentAnimation = new TWEEN.Tween(sprite.position).to({
            x : segment.endpoint.x,
            y : segment.endpoint.y,
            z : segment.endpoint.z
        }, animationTime).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None);

        currentAnimation.delay(delayTime * currentSpriteNumber);
        previousAnimation.chain(currentAnimation);
    }
    lastAnimation.chain(firstAnimation);
    lastAnimation.onComplete(onEachSpriteAnimationCompleted);
}

// start the animations
for each (sprite) {
    spriteFirstAnimation.start();
}

// to remove the delay when each sprite animation has made one loop, 
// and instantly replace the sprite at the beginning of the path 
// (my paths are not closed)
var onEachSpriteAnimationCompleted = function() {
    sprite.position.set(starting position);

    for each (sprite animation) {
        animation.delay(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, more than 2 years, near 1K view but no reply :lol:     
I suggest TweenJS for animation ;)

Comment: i didnt see the issue post so i added it [here](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/issues/201)